# Windows 8 protocol activation of Desktop app from a Modern App

Tags: winapi, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have two versions of my custom software. The Modern/Metro app (AppM) and my legacy Desktop application (AppD).  I have created a custom protocol for AppM using the manifest that is well understood.  I've edited the registry to make a custom protocol handler for AppD and have tested that I can indeed launch AppD using protocol activation from the Run dialog (WIN+R) by supplying the protocol and hitting enter, "AppD://" in this case.  I'd like to be able to launch AppM from AppD and AppD from AppM.  I've added handlers for each. In AppD I'm using Process.Start(uri) and in AppM I'm using Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri).  I can get AppM to launch from AppD but I never get AppD to launch from AppM.  I've googled and can't find any references to this.  I'm assuming it's not possible and might very much have to do with permissions.  As this assignment has fallen to me on the project, I need to either prove that it's not possible or find a solution.

I've tested this out using C#/XAml as well as HTML/JS and it's interesting to find that Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(uri).when() success function is called, but the success flag is false.  there is no error (or at least the err function is never hit).  I'd like to get a better error message and I'm currently trying to dig down that way.

So help with the actual issue, or help with how to debug this would both be greatly appreciated.

Update: To eliminate my own code, I downloaded and installed the [launch by association example](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Association-Launching-535d2cec) and simply changed the *var uriToLaunch= "http://bing.com"* to *var uriToLaunch= "AppD:"* and it fails every time.  This protocol is associated in the registry and the method that I'm using to verify this is by running it using WIN+R from the desktop and the app launches just fine.

Comment: Based on read of some of the msdn links, it looks like possible but not conclusive. 

I would suggest few things - 
1) refer remarks under these links in msdn and try out. [link1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh452690.aspx) [link2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh701484.aspx)
2) download this [association sample](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?linkid=231484) and try launch open with flow

Comment: thanks for the tip on the association sample.  I've updated the post to include my adventures there as well.  It's looking like launching desktop apps from modern apps might be blocked.

Comment: Microsoft reject apps that do this.

Answer (score 0):

[BatRT](http://isys-labs.com/batrt/) is an application which allows you to run a batch file from a metro app, utilizing URI calls. This should solve your problem.
Simply create a batch file within your metro app, then utilize BatRT to execute the batch file. Code snippets are available at the link above.